# Wordpress admin "don't have permission" due to incorrect URL structure

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress install which has a problem in previewing drafts.

`Sorry, you are not allowed to preview drafts.`

Browsing the website, the url is
`http://example.com`

The Wordpress files are actually stored in `http://example.com/wordpress`

So the Wordpress address url in settings is `http://example.com/wordpress` and the site url is `http://example.com/` as it should be.

In wp-admin though, it redirects to
`http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin`

An issue arises when you want to preview a post or page, and it says you are not allowed to view drafts.

The error shows up and the url looks like,
`http://example.com/hello-world/?preview_id=1&preview_nonce=cf457b8a3e&post_format=standard&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true`

But if you manually go to `http://example.com/wordpress/hello-world/?preview_id=1&preview_nonce=cf457b8a3e&post_format=standard&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true`

Then, everything works as intended. Stumped.

More details:

There are no plugin conflicts, nor theme conflicts.

This is not the typical Wordpress imlementation, because there is something that is pointing to calling the Wordpress index as it is not always called by the app.

It calls `require_once $path . '/wordpress/index.php';` why it does so is another story.

But, this is never even called, because wp-load decides to throw the error before then. Additionally, browsing the site with the urls, does not show the admin bar. Only when you manually add the directory.

I suppose it's possible this is somehow related to the `__()` added to Wordpress 4.7.

Comment: You tried this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory - As it states, WordPress does not particulary like it's own directory, so doing so requires some moderations, the link provides different methods for how this can be achieved.

Comment: Just another quick thought, you sometimes have to visit settings > permalinks in order for the links to all be correctly updated, might be worth a try?

Comment: Yes I've gone through those things. What determines the preview url for the post/page? My understanding is that wp-admin will always show as the full url, but for whatever reason viewing the pages works, previewing them with edits does not (without the added directory). If the preview url could be fixed, that would be a solution I guess